# Getting list of bucket GCS between two dates using PHP

Tags: php, cloud, storage, bucket

I'm trying to create some function with google client storage.
I need to fetch all bucket list within 2 dates given.

I used prefix, but it only using single pattern.

My code :

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket;

class BucketLog{

    function __construct(){
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->config('bucket_config', true);
        $this->project_id   = $this->CI->config->item('project_id', 'bucket_config');
        $this->bucket_name  = $this->CI->config->item('bucket_name', 'bucket_config');
        $this->key_file     = 'something_to.json';
    }

    function bucket_config(){
        $data = [    
            'keyFilePath' => $this->key_file,
            'projectId' => $this->project_id
        ];
        return $data;
    }

    function connect(){
        $storage = new StorageClient($this->bucket_config());
        return $storage->bucket($this->bucket_name);
    }

    function get_bucket_list(){
        $start_date     = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->CI->start_date); 
        $end_date       = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->CI->end_date); 
        $prefix         = sprintf("bucket_%s.dir", $this->CI->param_bucket);
        $prefix_regex   = preg_quote($prefix, '/');
        $bucketConnect  = $this->connect();
        $buckets  = $bucketConnect->objects([
            'prefix'    => $prefix,
        ]);
        $bucket_within_date = new \CallbackFilterIterator($buckets->objects(),
            // Only leave objects named within the start and end date
            // (includes start and end date)
            // BUCKET PATTERN bucket_dir/bucket_param.dir/year/month/date
            function (Bucket $buckets) use ($prefix_regex, $start_date, $end_date) {
                if (!preg_match($buckets->name(), '/^'.$prefix_regex.'_(\d{8})$/', $match)) {
                    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $match[1]);
                    return ($date >= $start) && ($date <= $end);
                }
                return false;
            },
        );
        return $bucket_within_date;
    }


    function reader(){
        $storage = new StorageClient($this->bucket_config());
        return $storage->registerStreamWrapper();
    }

}
```

Calling From Controller

```
function bucket_log(){
        $this->load->library('bucketlib/bucketlog');
        $this->param_bucket         = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->start_date   = '2023-06-12';
        $this->end_date     = '2023-06-15';
        print_r($this->bucketlog->get_bucket_list());
    }
```

I need to make the prefix could sort and filter bucket pattern between two dates.

I'm avoiding using loop for 2 dates as param, and hoping someone knows if there's any parameter inside `$bucket_connect->objects([]);` which is able to filter data from two dates. I've searched in gcs documentation but no luck.

any clue ?

thank in advance

Comment: I don't think bucket have "date". If you name the buckets with date information, you may simply parse the bucket names from the object list and then filter out the buckets by the parsed date.

Comment: Hi @KoalaYeung, i've tried your code but getting error, `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google\Cloud\Storage\ObjectIterator::objects()` , to be precised, i've updated my question code

Comment: Seems your `$bucket_log->connect()` method already returns an `Iterator` implementation. I've simplified my answer for that. Please check if it works.

Comment: It return empty `CallbackFilterIterator Object ( )`, from your answer, where's to call the bucket name ? because in my connect() function i'm using `bucket('bucket_name')`, meanwhile you are using only `buckets()`

Comment: Let me clarify. Do you want to list all your buckets (supposedly dynamically created) by their name (supposedly named by date)? Or do you want to list all objects in one specific bucket that are created between 2 dates?

Comment: actually it in 1 specific bucket, let say the name is `my_bucket` and then , inside it there are many sub-dir which is patterned by something like this `bucket_param.fixword`, sub-dir `YEAR`, sub-dir `month`, sub-dir `date`, and inside it will contain files i need to echo on user interface, so, i want to filter that sub-dir name by date from `my_bucket`, so all name will display like this `bucket_param.fixword/YEAR/MONTH/DATE`

Comment: Updated my code. Please check if it works. If not, its probably close enough for you to tweak.

Answer (score 0):

```php
use \Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use \Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject;

...

public function get_bucket_list(): \Iterator
{
    $start_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->CI->start_date); 
    $end_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->CI->end_date); 
    $prefix = sprintf("bucket_%s.dir", $this->CI->param_bucket);
    $bucketConnect  = $this->connect();
    $objects  = $bucketConnect->objects([
        'prefix'    => $prefix,
    ]);
    
    // Create an iterator of objects by their name.
    return new \CallbackFilterIterator(
        $objects,
        // Only leave objects named within the start and end date
        // (includes start and end date)
        function (StorageObject $object) use ($prefix_regex, $start, $end) {
            if (!preg_match($object->name(), '#^bucket_param.fixword/(?<year>\d{4})/(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<filename>.+?)$#', $match) {
                $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $match['year'] . $match['month'] . $match['day']);
                return ($date >= $start) && ($date <= $end);
            }
            return false;
        },
    );
}
```